# How to use Fit with exponential functions?

Tags: fitting, homework

"Use `Fit` to find the fourth degree polynomial that matches best the function $y=e^x$ at the points that have x-coordinates: -2, -1, 0, 1, 2."

What I tried:

```
data = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}
Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]
```

I even tried:

```
quart = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]
```

It gives me some weird reply:

```
3. + 1. Point[{7.788, 0, 1.95}] + 
 6.10382*10^-15 Point[{7.788, 0, 1.95}]^2 - 
 1.37899*10^-15 Point[{7.788, 0, 1.95}]^3 + 
 1.05752*10^-16 Point[{7.788, 0, 1.95}]^4
```

And how do I compare with $y=e^x$?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have defined `x` as `Point[{...}]`. Also, your code, as presented does not contain anywhere the ordinate values, only the abscissa values.

Comment: I will clean the x:s. But I wrote CleanAll in the start, isn't it supposed to clean all? I only have absices values. Oh, you mean I have to put e^x as ordinees values?

Comment: `CleanAll` is not a keyword in MMA (`ClearAll` is). Please use the documentation and note that `CleanAll` is likely blue when you type, not black, like predefined functions. Yes, indeed you have to put e^x, otherwise MMA doesn't know, what you're fitting to what.

Comment: I wrote ClearAll on my mathematica sheet, I swear!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

You need to first make a list of points:

```
f[x_] := E^x
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

> {{-2, 1/E^2}, {-1, 1/E}, {0, 1}, {1, E}, {2, E^2}}

to which you can fit the polynomial as you intended:

```
fit = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]
```

> `1. + 0.962458 x + 0.493925 x^2 + 0.212743 x^3 + 0.0491561 x^4`

You can immediatelly compare it with the Taylor series of $e^x$:

```
Series[f[x], {x, 0, 4}] // Normal // N
```

> `1. + x + 0.5 x^2 + 0.166667 x^3 + 0.0416667 x^4`

and finally make a nice-looking plot:

```
Plot[{f[x], fit}, {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Blue, Thick, Dashed}}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[data]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"polynom. fit", "Exp[x]"}, FrameLabel -> {"x", ""}]
```

[image]

---

You might want to take a look at [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html), too.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer @corey979! Why do I need 
f[x_] := E^x
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -2, 2}]

I tried to do it without the table and I get the same results, I think...

Comment: "You need to first make a list of points" and `Table` does just that. Read also carefully the docs of `Fit`. Additionaly, the function definition `f[x_] := E^x` (with the `SetDelayed` - `:=`) is just a useful construct worth knowing and using.